# Python Multiprocessing does not wait

Tags: python, process, operating-system, multiprocessing

I am currently using multiprocessing functions to analyze roughly 10 files.

However, I only want to run 5 processes at each time.

When I try to implement this, it doesn't work. More processes are created then the number I specified. Is there a way that easily limits the number of processes to 5? (Windows 7 / Python 2.7)

**EDIT:**
I'm afraid your solutions still don't work. I will try to post some more details here;

Main python file;

```
import python1
import python2 
import multiprocessing

# parallel = [fname1, fname2, fname3, fname4, fname5, fname6, fname7, fname8, fname9, fname10]
if name == '__main__':
   pool = multiprocessing.Pool(processes=max(len(parallel), 5))
   print pool.map(python1.worker, parallel)
```

Python1 file;

```
import os
import time
import subprocess

def worker(sample):
    command = 'perl '+sample[1].split('data_')[0]+'methods_FastQC\\fastqc '+sample[1]+'\\'+sample[0]+'\\'+sample[0]+' --outdir='+sample[1]+'\\_IlluminaResults\\_fastqcAnalysis'
    subprocess.call(command)
    return sample
```

The return statement of 12 files come back befóre all the opened perl modules have closed. Also 12 perl shells are opened instead of only the max of 5. (Image; You can clearly see that the return statements come back before the perl commands even finish, and there are more than 5 processes http://oi57.tinypic.com/126a8ht.jpg)

Answer (score 0):

I don't know why it is a secret what exactly doesn't happen and what happens instead.

And providing a [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/) means a program that actually runs. (Have a look at the `worker()` function, for example. It gets a `file` parameter which is never used, and uses a `command` variable which is nowhere defined.)

But I think it is the point that your `fileX` are just file names and they are tried to be executed.

Change your function to

```
def worker(filename):
    command = "echo X " + filename + " Y"
    os.system(command)
```

and it should work fine. (Note that I changed `file` to `filename` in order not to hide a built-in name.)

BTW, instead of `os.system()` you should use the `subprocess` module.

In this case, you can do

```
import subprocess

def worker(filename):
    command = ["echo", "X", filename, "Y"]
    subprocess.call(command)
```

which should do the same.

Just as a stylistic remark:

```
pool = multiprocessing.Pool(processes=max(len(parallel), 5))
```

is simpler and does the same.

---

Your edit makes the problem much clearer now.

It seems that due to unknown reasons your perl programs exit earlier than they are really finished. I don't know why that happens - maybe they fork another process by themselves and exit immediately. Or it is due to windows and its weirdnesses.

As soon as the multiprocessing pool notices that a subprocess claims to be finished, it is ready to start another one.

So the right way would be to find out why the perl programs don't work as expected.

Comment: Your method did not work for me. I've post some more details in my main question. (Perhaps I should have mentioned that I imported other python files, apologies for that)

Answer (score 0):

I tried with the following code under Linux with python-2.7 and it doesn't assert. Only 5 processes are created at a time.

```py
import os
import multiprocessing
import psutil
from functools import partial

def worker(pid, filename):
#    assert len(psutil.Process(pid).children(recursive=True)) == 5  # for psutil-2.x
    assert len(psutil.Process(pid).get_children(recursive=True)) == 5
    print(filename)

parallel = range(0, 15)

if __name__ == '__main__':
#    with multiprocessing.Pool(processes=5) as pool:  # if you use python-3
    pool = multiprocessing.Pool(processes=min(len(parallel), 5))
    pool.map(partial(worker, os.getpid()), parallel)
```

Of course, if you use os.system() inside the worker function, it will create extra processes and the process tree will look like (using os.system('sleep 1') here)

```
\_ python2.7 ./test02.py
    \_ python2.7 ./test02.py
    |   \_ sh -c sleep 1
    |       \_ sleep 1
    \_ python2.7 ./test02.py
    |   \_ sh -c sleep 1
    |       \_ sleep 1
    \_ python2.7 ./test02.py
    |   \_ sh -c sleep 1
    |       \_ sleep 1
    \_ python2.7 ./test02.py
    |   \_ sh -c sleep 1
    |       \_ sleep 1
    \_ python2.7 ./test02.py
        \_ sh -c sleep 1
            \_ sleep 1
```

Comment: Your method did not work for me. I've post some more details in my main question. (Perhaps I should have mentioned that I imported other python files, apologies for that)

Comment: It's not, per se, 'my method'. It's just how multiprocessing works.
Try this code without your perl script. If it works, your problem comes from the perl script creating detached subprocesses.